# Delete Row In Data Frame And Have That Work Across Functions - Reference Variable?

Tags: r, pointers, dataframe

I am creating a blackjack simulator in R and came upon an unexpected issue.  In the hit function, I want to remove a card from the deck, which is stored as a data frame.  The deletion works, however, getting the newly reduced data frame to be recognized in other functions doesn't work.  In other words, when I call the hit function and pass the data frame, deck, a copy of deck is passed.

I think this can be handled using reference variables or pointers but I  don't see much discussion of that online with R.  Also, using a global variable for the deck would work but I know that is not very popular.

When the print(str(deck)) line is executed from the hit function, the data frame consists of 51 objects which is correct.  When it is then executed from the Main function, it contains 52 objects.  I'd like the data frame with 51 objects to be recognized from now on.

Here is the code.  You can run the Main function and it will generate everything I discussed:

```
Main <- function()
{
  setDir()

  deck <- createDeck()
  hit(deck)
  print(str(deck))

}

hit <- function(deck)
{
  randomNum <- sample(nrow(deck),1) #Row index in data frame of card to be dealt
  card <- deck[randomNum,]
  deck <- deck[-randomNum,]

  print(card)  
  print(str(deck))
}

createDeck <- function(totalNumOfDecks = 1)
{
  suits <- c("Diamonds", "Clubs", "Hearts", "Spades")
  cards <- c("Ace", "Deuce", "Three", "Four","Five", 
             "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", 
             "Jack", "Queen", "King")
  values <- c(0,2,3,4,5,
              6,7,8,9,10,
              10,10,10)

  deck <- data.frame(Suit=character(0), Card=character(0), Value=numeric(0))

  numOfDecks = 1

  while (numOfDecks <= totalNumOfDecks){
    for (i in suits){
      for (j in cards){
        deck <- rbind.data.frame(deck, cbind.data.frame(j, i, values[match(j, cards)]))
      }
    }
    numOfDecks = numOfDecks + 1
  }

  colnames(deck) <- c("Card", "Suit", "Value")

  return (deck)
}

setDir <- function()
{
  setwd("/Users/michaelsankari/Documents/Trading & Investment/Ideas & Analysis/Blackjack")
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You probably just meant to have `hit()` actually return the modified version of `deck`, so in `Main` you'd do `deck <- hit(deck)`. But really, you're going to want to re-think your entire approach here. Cause what you're doing is writing Java code in R, or something, and that isn't going to be very helpful for learning R, I think.

Comment: If you modify `deck` in `hit()`, it will not be modified outside the function (see e.g. http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#lexical-scoping). You can modify the global variable inside the function using `<<-` or `assign(..., envir = .GlobalEnv)` but it is not a good idea. A more functional programming approach like @joran suggested would be better.

Comment: @joran, You hit the nail on the head!  I am more familiar with R than java.  My idea to speed along my learning in java is to write a blackjack simulator.  However, that was so complicated to me that I figured it would be easier to write it in R first just to get the structure.  Your point is making me think that I am better off struggling through writing it in java from the outset.  As to your point of having hit() return the deck, the idea of hit() is to return the card being dealt.

Comment: If your ultimate goal is a finished product in Java, R is going to be a very poor environment for prototyping. It uses an entirely different paradigm.

Comment: @joran Fair enough.  Let me take a step back and ask a bigger question.  If you were building a blackjack simulator and could choose between writing it in R or Java, which language would you choose?

Comment: I would choose R, because I've been using R on a daily basis for over a decade. My last serious experience with Java was in college, long long ago.